# Returm empty string for input when no results found in the array for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The following is my reverse geocoding javascript:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
              $.each(results[0].address_components, function(i,v) {
                if (v.types[0] == 'postal_code') {
                  $('#zip').val(v.long_name);
                }
                if (v.types[0] == 'locality') {
                  $('#city').val(v.long_name);
                }
                if (v.types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1' || v.types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_2') {
                  $('#state').val(v.long_name);
                }
                if (v.types[0] == 'country') {
                  $('#country').val(v.long_name);
                }
              });
              $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
              $('#lat').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
              $('#lng').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
            } else {
              alert("No results found. Please revise your address or adjust your marker.");
          }
        });
      });
```

First when the result for `City` is `AAA`, then the `input[type=text]#city` will be `AAA`. When I reverse geocode again, the return address does not have `city` in it. Instead of clearing the previous values, the `AAA` is left in the input text field.

Is there any way to clear the field when no results returned?

Thanks.

Comment: couldnt you clear it when the function is run, regardless

Comment: Sorry, javascript noob here. How do I clear them when it is run? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just clear it when the function is run like so

```
//put this at the top of your function
$('#address').val("");
```

Do the same for any other fields you need to clear